# jenkins - groovy - traversing all previous runs is very slow

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following groovy code:

```
build.getProject()._getRuns().iterator().each{ run ->
  // This is quick, so this is first
  if (run.isBuilding()) {
     // Never reach here
  }
}
```

My project has about 10k previous runs.
This loop takes about 15 minutes even when the condition is never fulfilled (no other active builds exist).

What is extra strange is that I have another project, with around 6k previous runs where it takes about 3 seconds to execute.

Why is that slow?

Is there a way to traverse that faster?

Since I'm only interested in active builds, is there a way to make that run faster?

Comment: I am curious why you would retain 1000's of previous run and not cler those logs?

Comment: I require documentation of the tests that each PR gone through

Comment: No mention of the timeframe to retain or rate of generation, but, must they remain in Jenkins? Keeping them in Jenkins does not add a level of surety. Can you not retain that evidence elsewhere? Can results from a prior interval (milestone or age) be archived off? In a prior role , when we delivered a release to the customer, (mission critical, human safety) we delivered all the test evidence, then we were done w/it. Records retaied off-line.